# spring-boot-starter-web project Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.hibernate:hibernate-validator:jar:5.3.5.Final

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, maven

I have a simple MVN project using spring-boot-starter-web, but it's throwing an error trying to get dependencies for Hibernate.

I have my POM:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" 
 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
 xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 
 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
   <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
   <groupId>com.mycompany</groupId>
   <artifactId>xsi-simulator</artifactId>
   <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>

<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.8.RELEASE</version>
</parent>

<properties>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>


<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>build-info</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>pl.project13.maven</groupId>
            <artifactId>git-commit-id-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>


 </project>
```

and the error is:

> [ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project xsi-simulator: Could not resolve dependencies for project com.tollring:xsi-simulator:jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT: Failed to collect dependencies at org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web:jar:1.5.8.RELEASE -> org.hibernate:hibernate-validator:jar:5.3.5.Final: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.hibernate:hibernate-validator:jar:5.3.5.Final: Could not transfer artifact org.hibernate:hibernate-validator:pom:5.3.5.Final from/to central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): repo.maven.apache.org: nodename nor servname provided, or not known: Unknown host repo.maven.apache.org: nodename nor servname provided, or not known -> [Help 1]

I've tried forcing an update with `-U`, and manually deleting all previous Hibernate jars in my m2 repo.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Can you ping or browse to repo.maven.apache.org? It looks like maven can't contact it.

Comment: Try `mvn clean install`

Comment: seems like `clean install` worked - but why did it work when `-U` didn't?  I thought -U would try to download the binary that was failing?